# Worker Role vs Azure Batch

Tags: azure, paas, azure-batch

We have a scenario for on prem to upload a bunch of pdf/tiffs then service on the cloud to process them. In the same time a queue is populated with metadata on processing instructions.

We are trying to decide if whether the worker role or the Azure Batch is the right choice for this. Our primary goal are,

- need to scalable base on queue size
- scale ramp up time need to be quick
- of course cost is another factor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PaaS cloud services are classic now, you can use webjobs with appservices. Another interesting option is AZURE STACK which is really good for hybrid cloud. refer this link 
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/overview/azure-stack AZURE STACK is really good for hybrid cloud, As if now it is in Technical preview.

Comment: azure stack will be over kill and until you try to become some kind of cloud provider on your own. I heard the cost is arround 500,000 $, but am not sure about the cost

Answer (score 1):

You should not use PaaS cloud services for new workloads. There are various options depending on the complexity of the processing you need to do. The following are likely better choices than Azure Batch: Azure [Web Jobs](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-create-web-jobs/#overview), [Virtual Machine Scale Sets](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/mt589023.aspx). The first is easier to use, and is based on the Web Apps technology, while the second is the (preview) way to provide scale-out VMs.

Comment: I would definitely start with Web Jobs. It is simple to write a web job that listens to a queue and processes each message (assuming by queue you meant a literal queue). Here's a good starting point: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/websites-dotnet-webjobs-sdk-storage-queues-how-to/